# Function finding contiguous regions in int [][]

Tags: java, arrays, int

I have a structure `int[][]`, with fixed size. It is filled with natural numbers. An example:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

My aim is to check how many contiguous regions of zeros in this structure I have. In this example the answer should be 4, which is a number of regions.
(no diagonals are taken into account).
Example solution:
First circle:

> **0 0 0 0 0 0 0**
>   1 2 6 9 **0** 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

Second one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 **0**
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 0

Third one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 **0** 2 1 1
>   1 2 **0 0 0** 1 0

Fourth one:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 2 6 9 0 3 4
>   3 1 3 4 5 6 0
>   1 2 3 0 2 1 1
>   1 2 0 0 0 1 **0**

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write the function and spoil the fun for you, but you can do it like this:

- Find every zero in your data. Mark it as its own region
- While your region-assignments are changing, do the following:

  - For each zero, check if there is a zero next to it. If there is and it belongs to another region, assign both to the same region.

When the region-assignments are no longer changing you can count the unique ones.